# Custom Fileds per Roles

Tags: members, control-panel

I am building website for startup. At this moment I am researching if EE will be good choice for this.
In this case I have 2 type of users. For example ServiceProviders and Buyers. I want for ServiceProviders to fill few more info when registering than Buyers.
Is this possible to do in EE with Roles? Maybe with some Addon?

Answer (score 1):

You can define easily the Role user in the control panel , members manager:

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/control-panel/member-manager.html

And after using the member Role tag manager:
https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/member/member-roles-tags.html

In the Member manager you will manage wich fields, templates associated for each role.

No add-on needed!